What legal restrictions apply to the use of public data accessed through APIs?
In the context of APIs, what legal restrictions govern the use of public data (e.g., data that does not require user authentication or permission)? Specifically, how do Terms of Service (TOS) agreements affect the aggregation and use of publicly accessible data via APIs, even when such data is freely available?
For example, the YouTube API's TOS (see [this link]) states that users cannot aggregate data from multiple channels or owners. What legal principles underlie such restrictions, and do similar rules apply to other types of public data accessed through APIs?

What legal principles underlie such restrictions - they own the data, they can define under which terms it is allowed to be used. Why is it even a question?

"public data" vs "publicly available data" need to be defined separately methinks.  "Ownership" of that data in the context of youtube is pretty cloudy.  Is it youtube's? Is it the creators?  It's likely that youtube tries to play both sides of that coin, but worth reading their Terms of Service: https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=GB&template=terms

Please spell out and explain all acronyms at least once, in this case API.

@ohwilleke I imagine that even most programmers who consume APIs have no idea what "API" stands for, and I doubt very strongly that many non-programmers would be helped by knowing that it stands for "application programming interface."  In this case, a brief explanation or link to a Wikipedia article probably makes more sense than simply spelling out the full name.

@phoog The point is that API is outside the average lawyer's knowledge.

Contract Law
In common law jurisdictions the licence for use to the API is a contract. That contract comes with terms (TOS). Breaching those terms is a contract violation which the innocent party can take action over - actions including suing for damages, obtaining an injunction, or terminating the contract.
It doesn’t matter if the breach involved doing things that would be legal if you hadn’t entered the contract because you did enter the contract and voluntarily agreed not to do those things.

"because you did enter the contract" How did you enter the contract?  You do not need to be aware of the contract or do anything to agree to it to use the API.

@User65535: a lawsuit, unlike criminal charges, does not include a presumption of innocence. Evidence that the api was discovered without reference to terms would go a long way towards a breech of contract suit, conversely lack of such evidence may be used to infer knowledge and agreement to the terms.

@jmoreno I am not sure I understand.  I you know that terms of service exist, but do not agree to them what difference does that make?  You can watch youtube without agreeing to the terms of service.

@User65535: the terms will include notice that using the API constitutes agreement to the terms.  That would not be true if you were unaware of the terms, but if you do, they may apply. I.e. you have apparently entered the contract, now the question is what that means.

@User65535 In order to access official APIs you need an API key. To get an API key you need to click a box that indicates acceptance of a contract. The questions start when you use the API key of another app, such as the android youtube app produced by Google, or when you automate the user interface of that app.

@CriticizeSEactionsmeansban If that was true then that would be the point of acceptance.  However I thought the API was used every time you watched an embedded video on a third party site, which you do without any explicit acceptance of a contract.
